# How to register a custom constraint validator

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, micronaut

My email string field is annotated with `javax.validation.constraints.Email`:

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;

public class MyModel {

  @Email
  private String email;
}
```

Currently hibernate-validator's `org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.AbstractEmailValidator` automatically validates it when the corresponding api endpoint is called:

```java
@Controller("/v1")
@Validated
public class MyController {
  ...

  @Put(uri = "/{id}")
  @Produces("application/json")
  public IdType updateEntity(@Valid MyModel model) {
    return delegate.updateEntity(model);
  }
}
```

How can I register my custom class to validate the email field with Micronaut's validator, while still using the original `javax.validation.constraints.Email` annotation?

This is what my custom constraint validator looks like:

```java
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;

@Singleton
public class EmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Email, String> {

  @Override
  public void initialize(Email constraintAnnotation) {}

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (value == null) {
      return true;
    }
    return value.contains("@");
  }
}
```

Micronaut version: 1.1.4

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you are looking for is this:

```
HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation
    .byProvider( HibernateValidator.class )
    .configure();

ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();

constraintMapping
        .constraintDefinition( Email.class )
        .includeExistingValidators( false )
        .validatedBy( MyEmailValidator.class );

configuration.addMapping( constraintMapping );
```

That's a programmatic way of "replacing" the existing validator for existing constraint. For more details on this check this part of the [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-constraint-definition)

Answer (score 0):

Change your validator from `@Email` to `@MailAdress` or any non-standard annotation.
Everyone expects `@Email` as an import from Javax / Hibernate.

If you want to add a behaviour you may also check `@Pattern` (as dot is not checked in `@Email` annotation)

Comment: Thanks, though this is not what I'm looking for. Note that in the question I stated "while still using the original `javax.validation.constraints.Email` annotation".

Comment: Changing your annotation name will grant you access to both @Email and your custom annotation ```@Email @CustomAnnotation public String myField;``` (And no one will be confused by your standard-like annotations)

Comment: The whole `MyModel` class is auto-generated code which should remain unchanged.